# Collection properties should be read only

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using FxCop for my WPF MVVM assembly and it gives me the error

> Collection properties should be read only

But in my property i need to RaisePropertyChangedEvent, now if i set the property to read only by removing its set section, how could i raise this event.

Syntax is somewhat like this

```
public List Employees
{
    get { return _employees; }
    set
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(_employees, value))
            return;
        _employees = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Employees");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rarely need to raise a PropertyChanged event on a collection. Make the collection observable so that it notifies any bindings whenever items are added or removed:

```
public IList<Employee> Employees
{
    get; 
    private set;
}

// in your constructor:
this.Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
```

Comment: Never say never... 

There are definitely valid situations when a collection property doesn't need to be read only! For example, if you are loading a large collection of data in a worker thread you want to load that data into a separate collection and then replace the existing collection entirely. This wouldn't be possible if you tried to make the changes in place because you would constantly need to invoke the changes on the main dispatcher.

Comment: lol ok - for the sake of avoiding the downvote I will change the wording. Let's just say that needing a settable collection is an edge case. FxCop is right.

Comment: A `readonly` keyword on a property? Did you notice the private setter?

Comment: I concede that it is technically possible to write to this property after the constructor, but it's your class - it's not like it's open to abuse.

Comment: @MattHamilton: (You need to address me explicitly, otherwise i won't get notified) Yes i did notice that, of course you cannot use that keyword on properties, the point is that this should not be done with an auto-property but with a normal one which *only* has a getter to a private readonly field. Otherwise the property *can* be overwritten inside the class at any point *by accident* which is something you should just make impossible *because you can*.

Comment: @H.B *shrug* ... I have plenty of apps in which I do exactly this. I see your point, but it's a lot of ceremony to set up a readonly field and associated property compared to the concise snippet above. Each to his own I guess.

Comment: @MattHamilton: You can create a VS-snippet for that sort of thing (surely i did), and it uses the same amount of lines, it's really not that much trouble.

Answer (score 2):

If you make your collection an ObservableCollection then the "important" events will be when items are added and removed from the collection, not when the collection is instatiated.  I agree, with FxCop.  Make the collection readonly, but make it an ObservableCollection